# Is it safe to store and version WordprocessingML documents in Subversion?

Tags: xml, svn, ms-word

Is it safe to store WordprocessingML documents in Subversion and perform conflict resolution on them? **Not** talking about OpemXML here - I'm wondering about Word's original single XML file format with binary image data, etc. all in a single **text** XML file.

Answer (score 2):

You can store any type of file you want in SVN, but you’ll only be able to take advantage of diffing and merging if the files are plain text.  You can always resolve conflicts manually.

Answer (score 0):

It depends by what you mean as safe? The data shoulnd't be corrupted. Of course anyone who has access to your SVN repository can see the file.

That being said, I would recommend against using SVN to store large data files with the intent of using it for finding differences. Although possible it's not really designed for that. You'll might also get some performance issues...

Answer (score 0):

Svn will safely version files that contain binary data if you mark them as binary. Of course if since they are marked as binary then you won't be able to do merges or conflict resolution.